# SoundPlayer.Stop() hangs, buzzes

Tags: c#, winforms, audio, .net-3.5, soundplayer

I play sound via SoundPlayer and stop it when a button is clicked. Parallel some timers are running in the background. On some computers the sound hangs (not the application, sort of buzzing), when stop is clicked. On some it works as excepted.

```
 SoundPlayer snd;

 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     snd = new SoundPlayer("mywave.wav");
     snd.Play();
 }

 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     snd.Stop(); // stops, but last sound is played in endless loop (hangs) on some machines
 }
```

Comment: Is this in WPF or WF?

Comment: it is Winforms .NET3.5

Comment: Can it be that you clicked the button twice and application crashed? Try placing `try{ snd.Stop(); } catch(Exception ex) { // TODO: Log }`

Comment: the application does not crash or hang. Only the sound hangs/buzzes

Comment: Could it be that you're instantiating new `SoundPlayer` before stopping the old one? Try checking if sound player is already initialized and stop it before assigning new one in first method. `if (this.snd != null) {this.snd.Stop(); this.snd.Dispose();}`